# How do i moq this DotNetOpenAuth Response object?

Tags: moq, dotnetopenauth

i have a method which takes in a [DotNetOpenAuth](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) (formally known as DotNetOpenId) `Response` object. My method extracts any claimed data, checks to see if this user exists in our system, yadda yadda yadda... and when finished returns the auth'd user instance.

Now .. how can i use *moq* to mock up this response object, to test my authentication method ( `AuthenticateUser()` )?

```
switch (response.Status)
{
    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

    User user = null;
    try
    {
        // Extract the claimed information and 
        // check if this user is valid, etc.
        // Any errors with be thrown as Authentication Errors.
        user = _authenticationService.AuthenticateUser(response) as User;
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException exception)
    {
        ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("AuthenticationError", exception);
    }

    .. other code, like forms auth, other response.status' etc. ..
}
```

Mocking framework: moq
Language: .NET C# 3.5 sp1
Response object: taken from the DotNetOpenAuth framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Moq in particular, but the response object is a type that implements `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.IAuthenticationResponse`, so it can be easily mocked by creating a class that implements the same interface and is prepared to return the same kinds of values.

...just downloaded Moq and mocked up an IAuthenticationResponse like so:

```
var response = new Mock<IAuthenticationResponse>(MockBehavior.Loose);
response.SetupGet(r => r.ClaimedIdentifier)
        .Returns("http://blog.nerdbank.net/");
response.SetupGet(r => r.Status)
        .Returns(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
response.SetupGet(r => r.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay)
        .Returns("blog.nerdbank.net");

IAuthenticationResponse resp = response.Object;
Console.WriteLine(resp.ClaimedIdentifier);
```

Obviously rather than send the result to `Console.WriteLine` you would want to pass the `resp` object to the method you're testing.

Comment: Hi Andrew - love the library! So, i should make a TestAuthenticationResponse object which impliments IAuthenticationResponse and just hard code the various fields i expect?

Comment: Thanks.  You could... although I just tried out Moq and updated my answer to show that you don't have to build this class that implements the interface yourself.  Enjoy.

Comment: <3 Andrew :)  All this Moq stuff totally confuses me :( So i sincerly thank you for your time in dl'ing moq, etc. Would we see any Moq tests in the MVC sample RP project, in the future (re: DotNotOpenAuth Visual Studion solution) ? :)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  Can you submit it to http://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com so I don't forget about it?

Comment: @AndrewArnott can you please look the question at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890185/iis7-dotnetopenauth-custom-linkedinclinet-response-is-not-available-in-current-c) and suggestion some solution?