# IIS7 DotNetOpenAuth Custom LinkedInClinet Response is not available in current context

Tags: iis-7, dotnetopenauth

I am using dotnetopneauth's Custom LinkedInClient available at following link:

[DotNetOpenAuth LinkedIn Client github link](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OAuth/LinkedInClient.cs)

It works on my development machine. I hosted it on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64-bit). It works fine there too. But I am switching it to another server with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit) and its creating problem here. On this server it gives me error "Response is not available in current context". Please see the attached image for stack trace.

[image: Stack Trace]

I've tried the solution at following link:

[Suggested solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326480/dotnetopenauth-in-iis7-request-not-available)

But it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and installed ASP.NET MVC 4 on my server and it worked for me.
ASP.NET MVC 4 download link:
[Download Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)